# Change the event in the Rotate library

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I am trying to implement this code: [my animation link](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/)

The problem is that I want to animate the picture when I click on a button, so here is my HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="change" onclick="go(30);"/>
</form>
```

and this is the script:

```
function go(deg){
 var value = 0
 $("#image").rotate({ 
 bind: 
      {  
    click: function(){
        value +=deg;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
      }
    } 

   });
 }
```

This code doesn't work, and it seems because of the click event inside the go() function.
Does anyone have the solution? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function go(value){
    $("#image").rotate({ // don't bind events here
        animateTo: value
    });
    return false;// to prevent submition of form
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/x9ja7/336/)** without click event.

**Pastebin Code** updated,

```
function go(){
   var val=0;
   var refreshId = setInterval( function(){
       val+=20;
       $("#image").rotate({ // don't bind events here
           animateTo: val
       });          
    },2000);
    return false;// to prevent submition of form
};
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/mecorehi/1)**

Comment: Shouldn't that be `animateTo: value` not `90`?

Comment: index.html (42) :SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+='

Comment: I associated the go() function to the onload event and I tested this code ( http://pastebin.com/KM5NCNxZ  ), unfortunately, I got these error messages:

index.html (68) :SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+='
index.html (24) :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: go

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can assign rotation simply on event *click*.

Code example from your link:

```
var value = 0;
$("#image").on('click', function () {
    value += 90;
    $(this).rotate({ animateTo: value })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form>
<input id="btn_rotate" type="submit" value="change" data-rotate="30"/>
</form>


   // do not add or change anything in here, it should work alone
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var value = 0
     $("#btn_rotate").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       value += $(this).attr("data-rotate");
       $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:value});
     });
   });
```

Comment: If it's data you should read it using [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) not attr.

Comment: Please explain your code a bit, and maybe add links to corresponding documentation pages. BTW, I agree with @Liam. Even if `attr` works fine, you can't be sure it will be the case in futures jQuery releases. That's always a good pratice to use methods for what they are supposed to do.

Comment: In this situation I am adding a simple attribute with a value, so if attr function accesses to all attributes of an element why should I not use this function? And I dont think that jQuery developers would cut off any functionality from attr function

Comment: I associated the go() function to the onload event and I tested this code ( pastebin.com/KM5NCNxZ ), unfortunately, I got these error messages: index.html (68) :SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+=' index.html (24) :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: go

Comment: If someone asks me to make some orange juice I **could** use my hands to squeeze the oranges (they do the job and my hands won't loose that functionality) but if I've got an orange squeezer it's much more practical and **efficient** to use that. Also, you don't know that Jquery will always support reading data attributes in this manner. If they decide to remove this functionality (which they would be well within their right to do) your code would fail.